# Regex which matches a string containing at least the specified characters

Tags: java, regex

I have a huge dictionary which I'm trying to look through using a regex. What I would like to do is to find all the words in the dictionary which contain at least one occurrences of each character I provide in no particular order.

Right now I can find words which only contain the specified characters but like I said that is not exactly what I want.

Example:

I want at least one occurrence of each of the following characters {b, a, d}

astring.matches(regex)

I would expect words like:

badder,
baddest,
baffled

Notice they all contain at least one occurence of each character but in no particular order and other characters are present in the strings.

Anyone know how to do this? Other suggestions are also welcome!

Comment: Do you really want/need to use regexp? If you plan to do many searches, other options may be more suitable.

Comment: No I don't. Are there any specific ways you have in mind?

Comment: "bafflegab" doesn't contain a "d". Can you please explain a but more of what you want?

Comment: whoops that shouldn't have been in there. As far as further explaining myself I just need at least one occurrence of each character that I specify to be in the string, I don't care about the order of it or if it has more than one of the characters specified or if it has unspecified characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a series of look-aheads:

```
^(?=.*b)(?=.*a)(?=.*d).*
```

which is a pain to construct. However, you can ease the pain by using regex to build it:

```
String regex = "^" + "bad".replaceAll(".", "(?=.*$0)") + ".*";
```

---

If using repeatedly with [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29), you would be better to use the following code, because *every* call to `String.matches()` compiles the regex again (there is no caching):

```
// do this once
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex); 

// reuse the pattern many times
if (pattern.matcher(input).matches())
```

Comment: It will now. I have edited it (slightly) - in java `matches()` must match the *whole* string

Comment: Very nice! Works like a charm! I don't know if using a regex is the most efficient way to do it but it works lol.

Comment: Thanks :) see edited answer for performance improvement. If you have measured speed, I would be interested to know how much faster you found using `Pattern` to be

Comment: w/o compiled regex = 00:01:637 sec w/ compiled regex = 00:00:493 sec. Wow! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lookahead to do this if it's available

```
(?=.*b)(?=.*a)(?=.*d)
```

However this is quite inefficient.  Any reason you can't use multiple `String.indexOf` checks?

Comment: No. I guess I was trying to find a one line option but it seems like its more trouble than just coding it up yourself.

Comment: If you split and sort the characters in the string, this will be straightforward.  In most scripting languages this will be a line liner:  `s.split('').sort.join('') =~ /a.*b.*d/i`

Comment: @Gene: Doesn't that require that they come in specific order? `/a.*b.*d/i` matches 'abd', but not 'bda'

Comment: @BenTaber it does but you could use the regex in my answer

Comment: Explosion, your regex doesn't seem to work with astring.matches(regex) i guess i should have specified that

Comment: @cstus what's in `astring`?

Comment: just any random String object. you had the right answer but Bohemian went a step further and made it work for .matches first

Comment: The Ruby code I gave (but java, javscript, Python and Perl would be similar), sorts the characters of the string so the order in the regex doesn't work.